# Use algo on Subgraph

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, subgraph

Let's say I have the following sub-graph (or a view):

```
MATCH(n:Person)-[]->(m:Person) RETURN n, m;
```

How could I run `CALL algo.louvain.stream` against the above result graph?

And further, how could I run `algo.scc` on each community find by `algo.louvain`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you hadn't found (or couldn't decipher) [the Neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/louvain/#algorithms-louvain-cp), here's the example provided:

```
CALL algo.louvain(
  'MATCH (p:User) RETURN id(p) as id',
  'MATCH (p1:User)-[f:FRIEND]-(p2:User)
   RETURN id(p1) as source, id(p2) as target, f.weight as weight',
  {graph:'cypher',write:true});
```

The docs don't say it explicitly, but the first query passed to `algo.louvain` specifies the collection of nodes to be considered by `algo.louvain` and the second query specifies the relationships among the nodes (or connected to the nodes) specified in query 1.

This means that you're going to have to specify whatever relationship type it is that's between the empty square brackets that you mentioned in the question. The algorithm won't run without something to connect the nodes— without edges to the vertexes, it's not a graph, after all.

Also, It is *crucially* important to replicate the `RETURN id(p1) as source, id(p2) as target` bit, no matter what the shape of your second query is, otherwise Java will throw an error.

Lastly, in terms of running `algo.scc` on each community, you'll need to modify the above query to specify the `writeProperty` in the configuration to `algo.louvain`. Once that query runs successfully, every node that was considered in the `algo.louvain` run will have a 0, 1, 2, etc. value as the property that you specified. Then, for each of these communities, you can call `algo.scc` [as in here](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/labs-algorithms/strongly-connected-components/#algorithms-strongly-connected-components-cp) with the same structure as the above call to `algo.louvain`; however in the first query passed to `algo.scc` you'll specify the community that you're after. For example (this is off the cuff based on your question, not from the docs):

```
// strongly-connected components for community 0
CALL algo.scc(
  'MATCH (n:Person {algo.louvain.writeProperty here: 0}) RETURN id(n) as id',
  'MATCH (n:Person)-[k:KNOWS]->(m:Person)
   RETURN id(n) as source, id(m) as target',
  {graph:'cypher',write:true,writeProperty:'partition'})
  YIELD loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, setCount, maxSetSize, minSetSize
```

Then, as the docs suggest, you can find the largest partition with the following:

```
MATCH (u:Person)
RETURN u.partition as partition,count(*) as size_of_partition
ORDER by size_of_partition DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

or further query your (sub)graph in any way that you choose because the results of the algorithms are written as properties on the `Person` nodes. HTH.

Comment: @Top.Deck Good to hear! :)